# variable is not an instance variable

Tags: reason

I made this factorial solver but all it outputs is:

```
  We've found a bug for you!
  6| let factorialNumber = 0;
  7| Js.log(factorial(factorialNumber));
(error here)8|  factorialNumber = factorialNumber + 1;
  9|}
The value factorialNumber is not an instance variable
```

The code

```
let rec factorial = (n) =>
  n <= 0
  ? 1
  : n * factorial(n - 1);
while (true){
  factorialNumber = 0
  Js.log(factorial(factorialNumber));
  factorialNumber = factorialNumber + 1
}
```

Comment: Your `factorialNumber` is an implicit global. You should declare it as `let factorialNumber = 0`

Answer (score 0):

In Reason, [variables are immutable by default](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/let-binding#bindings-are-immutable). You're also not declaring `factorialNumber` as a variable anywhere.

The changes needed to make this compile is:

1. Declare the variable using `let`
2. Make the variable a [mutable reference](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/mutable-bindings) using `ref`
3. Access the value of the reference using `^`
4. Assign a new value to the reference using `:=`

```
while (true) {
  let factorialNumber = ref(0);
  Js.log(factorial(factorialNumber^));
  factorialNumber := factorialNumber^ + 1
}
```

This still doesn't make much sense, however, as you're still just running `factorial(0)` on every iteration. I suspect what you want is to move the declaration and initial assignment outside the loop, so that it's incremented by one on each iteration:

```
let factorialNumber = ref(0);

while (true) {
  Js.log(factorial(factorialNumber^));
  factorialNumber := factorialNumber^ + 1
}
```

Comment: Also, there is a built-in function `incr` which adds `1` to an `int` reference: `incr(factorialNumber);` instead of `factorialNumber := factorialNumber^ + 1;`